# Find third Max salary using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning LINQ and I want to find third max salary using LINQ. I know how to query collections but I am unable to figure out out to solve this problem

```
void Main()
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Salary = 1500 });
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Wow", Salary = 10000 });
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Bill", Salary = 1000 });
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Jane Doe", Salary = 2000 });

    var secondHighestSalary=from e in employees
                select e ----

}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A simple solution is to sort the list and take the 3rd item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try following code snippet

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Salary = 1500 });
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Wow", Salary = 1800 });
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Bill", Salary = 1000 });
    employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Jane Doe", Salary = 2000 });

    var secondHighestSalary=employees.OrderByDescending(e => e.Salary)
            .Skip(2)
            .Take(1);
secondHighestSalary.Dump();
```

Comment: I am using Linqpad Dump is part of LinqPad .Just remove the Dump method if you using visual studio